# How can I make my HTML to be never cached, while caching all images, stylesheets, and other resources?

Tags: html, http, caching, cache-control

I have a site with a front page that is static HTML but whose content may vary from time to time.  I want all browsers to update contents if changed since last page load.  At the same time caching is great for images, stylesheets, javascript, and other resources.

Is `Cache-Control` header the right option?  Would this `Cache-Control` header do the tricK?

```
Cache-Control: max-age=3600, must-revalidate
```

If not, which?

Comment: What is the web server application? IIS? Apache?

Comment: If I recall, static files such as `htm`s are served using an ETag by default, which causes the browser to locally store the response and check for modifications if any on the next request. (Try Fiddler to sniff the HTTP requests and responses.) Isn't this the behavior you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Cache-Control: no-cache` will work great if you don't want any part of the page to be cached.

But if you need to cache the page, except for a particular section, try using this alternative approach:

1. Cache your entire page using `Cache-Control: public, max-age=XYZ`, where XYZ is the time in seconds.
2. Load the not-to-be-cached section using Ajax.

Example code:

```js
var loadSection = function(section) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/section/' + section + '.html',
        cache: false
      }).done(function(html){
        $('#main-content').html(html);
        w.pageCache[section] = html;
      });
    }
};
```

For a live implementation, see http://jagteshchadha.com

Comment: Thanks Jagtesh, but which is the right Cache-Control header if I want my HTML to be reloaded everytime it is changed in the server?

Comment: Sure. `Cache-Control: no-cache`. This will ensure the page is never cached.

Answer (score 1):

why do you not use an .htaccess ?

with all Expires Header, you want to control all exipres files by type:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive on

# Perhaps better to whitelist expires rules? Perhaps.
  ExpiresDefault                          "access plus 1 month"

# cache.appcache needs re-requests in FF 3.6 (thx Remy ~Introducing HTML5) 
  ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest       "access plus 0 seconds"



# your document html
  ExpiresByType text/html                 "access plus 0 seconds"

# data
  ExpiresByType text/xml                  "access plus 0 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/xml           "access plus 0 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/json          "access plus 0 seconds"

# rss feed
  ExpiresByType application/rss+xml       "access plus 1 hour"

# favicon (cannot be renamed)
  ExpiresByType image/x-icon              "access plus 1 week"

# media: images, video, audio
  ExpiresByType image/gif                 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/png                 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/jpg                 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg                "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType video/ogg                 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType audio/ogg                 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType video/mp4                 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType video/webm                "access plus 1 month"

# htc files  (css3pie)
  ExpiresByType text/x-component          "access plus 1 month"

# webfonts
  ExpiresByType font/truetype             "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType font/opentype             "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType font/woff                 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/svg+xml             "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 month"

# css and javascript
  ExpiresByType text/css                  "access plus 2 months"
  ExpiresByType application/javascript    "access plus 2 months"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript           "access plus 2 months"

  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header append Cache-Control "public"
  </IfModule>

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

For your css and javascript scripts you can use versions like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css?v=1.0.0" type="text/css" />
```

and with the next update you will change the version. You can do the same with .js scripts and also with images sources, if you really need it.

Comment: That is the way I force resources to be refreshed when I need it, :-)  But the important thing is, how do I force my HTML to be updated in browser's cache everytime it is modified in server?

Comment: Matei: I think you missed the point of the question. antur123 wants it the other way around.